# How did these apples grow together?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, fruit

I came through this pic while scrolling through facebook, and it was a bit strange to me.

As far as I know apples have a corymbose type of inflorescence, in which a single pedicel ends in a single thalamus.

And I am totally sure that the edible part, which is fleshy in the apple, is thalamus. How did this fruit came into existence?

I want a biological answer for this query.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are basically conjoined apples which share a common stalk. They are rare but do happen. Here is [an article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2433619/Siamese-apples-Conjoined-fruit-discovered-lying-ground-mans-garden.html) of one discovered in a backyard.

[image]

conjoined apple discovered in a store ([reference](http://www.topix.com/album/detail/dittmer-mo/DRC833GMCVJKJMF3))

It apparently happens because of bad weather conditions, stress and insect damage. Fused fruits are also found in the case of cherries, watermelons, peaches etc.

> Inadequate pollination because of heat and other adverse growing
>   conditions causes that section of the fruit in which the seed did not
>   develop to not grow and fill out. Also, the fruit primordium
>   (embryonic growing point) can be damaged or altered by environmental
>   factors and cause strange growth forms. Of course, Siamese twins or
>   two fruit growing together is also rather common([reference](http://www.plantanswers.com/vegetable_shapes_gallery.htm)).

Read more about them on [article 1](http://www.weirdasianews.com/2010/07/27/freaky-conjoined-watermelon-weird-fruit-mutations/) and [article 2](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/environmental/what-is-plant-buttoning.htm).

Comment: that was very well explained thanks for this answer.